# Android: Miracast: prependSPSPPSToIDRFrames

Tags: android

In Android 4.2 release, I observe that the `miracast` implementation mandates an `OMX` encoder to support a new extension index  "**OMX.google.android.index.prependSPSPPSToIDRFrames**". However, when I studied the subsequent implementation of `MediaCodec`, `Converter` and `WifiDisplaySource`, I observe that there is enough support in the existing framework to support this feature without the need of adding another index for the `OMX` component.

Can someone please confirm if my understanding is correct? If so, can you kindly provide some further information on reasons/rationale behind the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answers to my question in latest release of `Android 4.2.2`. As per my earlier question, Google has decided to support both an `index` inside the `OMX Component` as well as a `Stagefright` framework level handling of `prepend SPS and PPS to IDR frames`. This way an `OMX Component` needn't support the new index. The creation of the component from `ACodec` interface doesn't fail and the framework takes up the responsibility of `prepend`.